# IIS Remote Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I have an IIS Application which references a plugin manager which reads all available plugins from a folder, when it is hosted after about 5-10 minutes I start getting the following Exception

```
[RemotingException: Object '/1608465e_9d80_4b40_be20_4c96904643e0/wizi+0g5od5gwmunm_indiws_253.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.]
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14416170
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +388
PluginManager.Core.Interfaces.IPluggin.get_Id() +0
PluginManager.PluginDetails.get_Id() +27
```

I did some research and came accross ILease and ISponsor but I have no Idea how to implement it or how it works. My current code as it is at this moment, I just removed parts the body of the methods for clarity
[Edit : added the method bodies]

```
public class AssemblyReflectionProxy : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private string _assemblyPath;

    public AssemblyReflectionProxy()
    {
        Id = "";
    }

    public void LoadAssembly(String assemblyPath)
    {
        try
        {
            _assemblyPath = assemblyPath;
            Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
        }
    }

    public TResult Reflect<TResult>(Func<Assembly, TResult> func)
    {
        var directory = new FileInfo(_assemblyPath).Directory;
        ResolveEventHandler resolveEventHandler = (s, e) => OnReflectionOnlyResolve(e, directory);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve += resolveEventHandler;
        var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyGetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(a => String.Compare(a.Location, _assemblyPath, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0);
        var result = func(assembly);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve -= resolveEventHandler;

        return result;
    }

    public T GetEntryType<T>()
    {
        var directory = new FileInfo(_assemblyPath).Directory;
        ResolveEventHandler resolveEventHandler = (s, e) => OnReflectionOnlyResolve(e, directory);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve += resolveEventHandler;
        var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyGetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(a => string.Compare(a.Location, _assemblyPath, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0);
        if (assembly != null)
        {
            var result = assembly.GetTypes();
            var type = result.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetInterface(typeof(T).Name) != null);
            if (type != null)
            {
                var remoteObject = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(type.Assembly.Location, type.FullName);                   
                var obj = remoteObject.Unwrap();
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve -= resolveEventHandler;
                return (T)obj;
            }
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    private Assembly OnReflectionOnlyResolve(ResolveEventArgs args, DirectoryInfo directory)
    {
        var loadedAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyGetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(asm => string.Equals(asm.FullName, args.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        if (loadedAssembly != null)
        {
            return loadedAssembly;
        }

        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
        var dependentAssemblyFilename = Path.Combine(directory.FullName, assemblyName.Name + ".dll");

        if (File.Exists(dependentAssemblyFilename))
        {
            return Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(dependentAssemblyFilename);
        }
        return Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(args.Name);
    }

    private string Id { get; set; }
    internal string GetId()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
        {
            var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(_assemblyPath);
            var hash = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes).GetHashCode();
            var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(hash);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in bytes)
                sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
            Id = sb.ToString();
        }
        return Id;
    }
}


public sealed class AssemblyManager : MarshalByRefObject, IDisposable
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, AppDomain> _assemblyDomains = new Dictionary<string, AppDomain>();
    readonly Dictionary<string, AssemblyReflectionProxy> _proxies = new Dictionary<string, AssemblyReflectionProxy>();
    public AssemblyManager()
    {

    }

    public string LoadAssembly(string assemblyPath)
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(assemblyPath);
        var name = fileInfo.Name.Replace(".dll", "");
        if (fileInfo.Exists)
        {
            if (!_assemblyDomains.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                var appDomain = CreateChildDomain(AppDomain.CurrentDomain, fileInfo.Name);
                _assemblyDomains[name] = appDomain;
                try
                {
                    Type proxyType = typeof(AssemblyReflectionProxy);
                    {
                        var proxy = (AssemblyReflectionProxy)appDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(proxyType.Assembly.Location, proxyType.FullName).Unwrap();
                        proxy.LoadAssembly(assemblyPath);
                        _proxies[name] = proxy;
                        return name;
                    }
                }
                catch
                { }
            }
            else
            {
                return name;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    public void Unload()
    {

    }

    private AppDomain CreateChildDomain(AppDomain parentDomain, string domainName)
    {
        var evidence = new Evidence(parentDomain.Evidence);
        var setup = parentDomain.SetupInformation;
        return AppDomain.CreateDomain(domainName, evidence, setup);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~AssemblyManager()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public IPluggin GetEntryPluggin(string name)
    {
        IPluggin plugin = default(IPluggin);
        if (_proxies.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            plugin = _proxies[name].GetEntryType<IPluggin>();
        }
        return plugin;
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            foreach (var appDomain in _assemblyDomains.Values)
                AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
            _assemblyDomains.Clear();
        }
    }

    internal string GetEntryPlugginID(string name)
    {
        string Id = "";
        if (_proxies.ContainsKey(name))
        {
            Id = _proxies[name].GetId();
        }
        return Id;
    }
}
```

My Interface is

```
public interface IPluggin
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Version { get; }
    string Id { get; }
    void Initialize();
    string[] GetElements();
    void SaveSettings(string settings);
    void SetBasePath(string path);
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating new `AppDomain`s in a hosted application? That sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: Because we write plugins to the application, when we pop a new dll in the plugin folder the application pics it up and loads it and then use it where applicable

Comment: The AppDomain allows us to "unload" a dll and load a new one (basically an updated dll)

Comment: Wait, you're saving DLLs in a different place than the bin folder? I hope you secured somehow it at least... The thing is, IIS uses application domains internally to isolate different applications running in the same application pool (i.e. process), and it makes sure that when application domains misbehave, they are terminated (and restarted). This might be what's causing your appdomains to be unloaded prematurely - IIS considers them broken, because they're not associated with any requests. Or there may be a hundred different problems, it's hard to tell :) Perhaps a service would be better?

Comment: I didn't think of that, I think I will look into creating a service for this, BUT I also think I might have solved the problem by doing the following

        public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
        {
            return null;
        }
The web app is now online for about 30 minutes where it crashed after 5-10 minutes. I will leave it and see tomorrow morning

Comment: Lifetime services are quite important in remoting - note that you just basically said that the remoting object should never be collected. This may be what you want, but maybe it would be better to simply handle the collection gracefully - if the object was collected, just create a new one.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, remoting is getting a bit more clear for me and fun to work with, Is there a way to test if the object was collected because just wrapping a try catch over the object would still give the exception and give the IIS error, good news is that returning null did indeed work tested this morning. But as you said it would be better to handle the collection gracefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET remoting is kind of deprecated, but I don't see why it would be a problem for communicating between application domains, so...

When you create a new instance of a remoting object, what you actually do is request the remote side to create one for you, while you only maintain a proxy. The remote side associates each of such objects with a *lease* - something that describes how the lifetime of the object is handled. This means that even if the client side still has strong references to the remote object, the remote object can be garbage collected when its lease expires.

The easiest way to check if this happened is using the `RemotingServices.GetLifetimeService` method. Just use it on the proxy object, and you will get the information you need - for example, `CurrentState` will tell you if the remote is still alive. If it is, you can also extend the lease using `Renew`.

So, the usual way to handle the lifetime of the remote object would be - check if it is still alive; if it is, extend the lease and do whatever you want. Make sure you check `CurrentLeaseTime` too - it's a good idea to maintain it some reasonable value, rather than always `Renew`ing a fixed amount of time.